# Flutter: How to add the data from the Firebase to a list for the chip widget?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

It's quite complicated to understand what to be done. I usually do not see any of the references that the chip widget using just `ListView()`. This is just the first time for me recently to do Chip Widget.

The problem here is if I consider `itemCount`, there will not have the firebase data added.
If I consider the firebase data to be added, `itemCount` will be an error.

I'm quite uncertain what I'm supposed to do for this. How can I add the entire firebase data into the list?

Desired function code:

```
productlist.add(Product(
buspickup: docdata['buspickup'],
busdropoff: docdata['busdropoff'],
price: docdata['price'],
period: docdata['period']));
```

Source Code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class Product {
  final String buspickup;
  final String busdropoff;
  final int price;
  final String period;

  Product({
    required this.buspickup,
    required this.busdropoff,
    required this.price,
    required this.period,
  });
}

List<Product> productlist = [
  // Product(buspickup: 'Schezar', busdropoff: 'Island', price: 5, period: 'Morning'),
  // Product(buspickup: 'Sandwich', busdropoff: 'Food', price: 2, period: 'Afternoon'),
];

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<String> categories = [
    'Morning',
    'Afternoon',
    'Night',
    'Midnight'
  ]; //Target "Category"
  List<String> selectedCategories = [];
  final originalList = productlist.toList(); //For the New List
  bool isActive = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final filterProducts = productlist.where((product) {
      return selectedCategories.isEmpty ||
          selectedCategories.contains(product.period);
    }).toList();

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Fitler Sorting"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Schedule').get(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshots) {
                  if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                    flex: 3,
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                      children: categories
                                          .map((category) => FilterChip(
                                              selected: selectedCategories
                                                  .contains(category),
                                              label: Text(category),
                                              onSelected: (selected) {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  if (selected) {
                                                    selectedCategories
                                                        .add(category);
                                                  } else {
                                                    selectedCategories
                                                        .remove(category);
                                                  }
                                                });
                                              }))
                                          .toList(),
                                    )
                                    ),
                              ],
                            )),
                        
                        SizedBox(
                            height: 500,
                            width: 500,
                            child: 
                            ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: filterProducts.length,
                                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                                  final DocumentSnapshot docdata = snapshots.data!.docs[index];
                                  // productlist.add(Product(
                                  //     buspickup: docdata['buspickup'],
                                  //     busdropoff: docdata['busdropoff'],
                                  //     price: docdata['price'],
                                  //     period: docdata['period']));
                                  
                                  final product = filterProducts[index];
                                  return Card(
                                      elevation: 8,
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                      child: Container(
                                        decoration:
                                            BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
                                        child: ListTile(
                                            contentPadding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                    horizontal: 10,
                                                    vertical: 10),
                                            title: Text(
                                              product.buspickup,
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            ),
                                            subtitle: Text(
                                              '${product.price}',
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              ),
                                            )),
                                      ));
                                }))
                                
                                ),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(child: Text("Loading"));
                  }
                }),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```